# proxy_fcgi:error: The timeout specified has expired: Error dispatching request to : (polling)

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm

my web server reaches the state of being unreachable every 1-2 days until I completely restart the server.

The server is Debian Bullseye with the newest Apache + PHP 7.4. I'm using FPM, because I want to have HTTP2. 16 GB RAM vServer.

`/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
[Sat May 07 18:01:57.970776 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 139033:tid 139719866291968] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client xxxIPxxx:47330] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
[Sat May 07 18:02:42.854791 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 269312:tid 139720560633600] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client xxxIPxxx:32702] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
```

Of course, I found different posts / solutions about this issue and I already increased the timeouts for PHP and FPM, but this bug is still there.

`/var/log/php7.4-fpm.log`:

```
[07-May-2022 07:05:01] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it                                                                                                                                                                                    
[07-May-2022 07:46:42] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it                                                                                                                                                                                    
[07-May-2022 09:14:09] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it                                                                                                                                                                                    
[07-May-2022 09:27:13] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it                                                                                                                                                                                    
[07-May-2022 12:27:16] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it                                                                                                                                                                                    
[07-May-2022 15:05:19] NOTICE: [pool www] child 265395 exited with code 0 after 13010.271694 seconds from start                                                                                                                                                                               
[07-May-2022 15:05:19] NOTICE: [pool www] child 267508 started                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[07-May-2022 15:13:40] NOTICE: [pool www] child 265396 exited with code 0 after 13510.447458 seconds from start                                                                                                                                                                               
[07-May-2022 15:13:40] NOTICE: [pool www] child 267637 started                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[07-May-2022 16:13:26] NOTICE: [pool www] child 265945 exited with code 0 after 13622.463297 seconds from start                                                                                                                                                                               
[07-May-2022 16:13:26] NOTICE: [pool www] child 268279 started                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[07-May-2022 17:42:16] NOTICE: [pool www] child 267508 exited with code 0 after 9417.705135 seconds from start                                                                                                                                                                                
[07-May-2022 17:42:16] NOTICE: [pool www] child 269286 started                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[07-May-2022 17:45:07] NOTICE: [pool www] child 267637 exited with code 0 after 9087.193478 seconds from start                                                                                                                                                                                
[07-May-2022 17:45:07] NOTICE: [pool www] child 269309 started                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[07-May-2022 19:20:39] NOTICE: Terminating ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[07-May-2022 19:20:39] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[07-May-2022 19:20:55] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 694                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[07-May-2022 19:20:56] NOTICE: ready to handle connections                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[07-May-2022 19:20:56] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and could fix it by creating `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-proxy_timeout.conf`.

As content try to add

```
Timeout xx
ProxyTimeout xx
```

Replace the xx with an amount of seconds suitable for your usecase. Just play around with the numbers and check if it can fix your problem.

Take a look at [this guide](https://shouts.dev/articles/apache-proxy-fcgi-the-timeout-specified-has-expired-on-rhel).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/523287)

Comment: @mforsetti I changed the post.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help. I tried this already a lot by increasing and decreasing these Timeout values.